# Ivy resolve in Eclipse when using local repository

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I set up a demo according to this link: [sample example which explain how to use filesystem resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175000/sample-example-which-explain-how-to-use-filesystem-resolver)

It works fine when I run ant via command line, I can see that Ivy downloads the jar files from local folder.

But in Eclipse, if I right click the project >> Ivy >> Resolve, it always down jar files from internet, and if I disconnect from internet, the resolve will fail.

Anyone have clues?

Comment: Have you configured your IvyDE classpath container in Eclipse so it takes into account the proper ivysettings.xml file ?

Comment: @Nicolas Lalevée, i just figure out that when right clicking ivy.xml and "add Ivy library", i should point it to my ivysettings.xml in "settings" tab page, thank you!