# ant junit task -- where to download ant-junit.jar and where to put it?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I literally wasted 2 hours trying to get ant junit task working. First, I had trouble finding `ant-junit.jar` file but I managed to find it in a maven page. After that I put it several places(`~/.ant/lib`, `/usr/share/ant/lib`) but no luck.. I'm still getting this error:

```
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
```

So I'm looking for:

1. Official web page to download ant junit task files
2. Correct place to put that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The Ant download distribution

Expurgated tree:

```
➜  apache-ant-1.9.4  tree lib
lib
├── ant-junit.jar
├── ant-junit4.jar
```

**2.** Your test classpath

Just like any other test dependency.

---

*Tangential: The distro (or a Maven repo/search) is generally the first place to look. It’s a few minutes to download, decompress, look for the JUnit-related files, and do a `tar xvf` to sanity-check the missing class ref.*

Answer (score 1):

You can download dependencies from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) from an ANT task as follows:

```
<available classname="org.junit.runner.Runner" property="junit.installed"/>

<target name="install-junit" description="Install junit" unless="junit.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>

    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-junit.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ant/ant-junit/1.9.4/ant-junit-1.9.4.jar"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/junit.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar"/>

    <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
</target>
```

An even better alternative is to use Apache ivy to manage dependencies. An example build file is here:

- [sample example which explain how to use filesystem resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175000/sample-example-which-explain-how-to-use-filesystem-resolver/10180491#10180491)