# Eclipse for java, package org.junit does not exist during Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ant

I recovered code that is ok from another PC.

At first open i had an error about this line :
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

I added Junit 4 library to fix it ,  no more syntax warning but

when i compile using an xml file with Ant (the same file and same way than previous pc), the error is:

- package org.junit does not exist     [javac] import static org.junit.Assert.*;

I use eclipse for java

Any idea ?

thanks in advance

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- ==================================================================
         menage du répertoire de compilation
         ================================================================== -->
    <target name="capteurs-menage">
        <delete dir="output"/>
        <mkdir dir="output" />
    </target>

    <!-- ==================================================================
         Compilation du projet
         ================================================================== -->
    <target name="capteurs-compile">    
        
        <!-- définit l'emplacement de javac, dans le jdk -->
        <property name="javac1.8.0_271" location="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/javac" />
        
        <!-- définit les dépendances du classpath dans une propriété -->
        <property name="build.class.prop" id="build.classpath" value="lib/guava-17.0.jar;lib/RXTXcomm.jar;lib/joda-time-2.7.jar;lib/jssc.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;lib/servlet-api.jar" />
        
        <!-- Compilation avec javac -->
        <!-- Envoi-javac srcdir="src" classpath="${build.class.prop}" destdir="output" includeantruntime="false" encoding="UTF-8"/>-->
        <javac executable="${javac1.8.0_271}"  
            srcdir="src"
            classpath="${build.class.prop}"
            destdir="output"
            includeantruntime="false" 
            encoding="UTF-8">
        </javac>
    </target>


    <!--*************************************
        Génération du jar avec les ressources
        ************************************* -->
    <target name="capteurs-jar">
        <delete file="$output/capteurs-${version}.jar" />
        
        <!-- numero de version de la librairie Capteurs-->
        <property name="versionCAPTEURS" id="versionCAPTEURS.prop" value="1.6" />
        
        <!-- Archivage du jar -->
        <jar destfile="output/capteurs-${versionCAPTEURS}.jar">
            <fileset dir="output" />
        </jar>
        
    </target>

    <!-- ==================================================================
         PROGRAMMES de test
         ================================================================== -->

    <!-- ==================================================================
         génération du programme de test : testRxTx.jar
         ================================================================== -->
    <target name="test-jar" depends="capteurs-compile">
        <delete file="output/testRxTx.jar" />

        <!-- Compilations complémentaires -->
        
        <!-- définit l'emplacement de javac, dans le jdk -->
        <property name="javac1.8.0_271" location="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/javac" />
        
        <!-- définit les dépendances du classpath dans une propriété -->
        <property name="build.class.prop" id="build.classpath" value="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" />
                        
        <!-- Compilation avec javac -->
        <javac executable="${javac1.8.0_271}"  
              srcdir="test"
              includes="fr/meteo/dsodos/common/TestRxTx.java"
              classpath="${build.class.prop}"
              destdir="output"
              includeantruntime="false">
        </javac>
        
        <!-- Ajout des dépendences -->
        <!-- copy file="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" todir="output" /-->
        <unjar src="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" dest="output" />

        <property name="versionCAPTEURS" id="versionCAPTEURS.prop" value="1.6" />

        <!-- Archivage du jar -->
        <jar destfile="output/testRxTx.jar">
            <fileset dir="output" />

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="fr.meteo.dsodos.common.TestRxTx" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                    <section name="common">
                        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="Test de la bibliothèque RxTx" />
                        <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${versionCAPTEURS}" />
                        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="DSI/DEV/AM" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="Test de la bibliothèque RxTx" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${versionCAPTEURS} ${TODAY}" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="DSO/DOS" />
                    </section>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- ==================================================================
         génération du programme de test
         ================================================================== -->
    <target name="test-compas" depends="capteurs-compile">
        <delete file="output/testCompas.jar" />

    <!-- Compilations complémentaires -->
        
        <!-- définit l'emplacement de javac, dans le jdk -->
            <property name="javac1.8.0_271" location="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/javac" />
        
        <!-- définit les dépendances du classpath dans une propriété -->
            <property name="build.class.prop" id="build.classpath" value="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" />
            
                                    
        <!-- Compilation avec javac -->
            <javac executable="${javac1.8.0_271}"  
                  srcdir="test"
                  includes="fr/meteo/dsodos/compas/TestCompas.java"
                  classpath="${build.class.prop}"
                  destdir="output"
                  includeantruntime="false">
            </javac>

        <!-- Ajout des dépendences -->
        <!-- copy file="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" todir="output" /-->
        <unjar src="lib/RXTXcomm.jar" dest="output" />

        <property name="versionCAPTEURS" id="versionCAPTEURS.prop" value="1.6" />

        <!-- Archivage du jar -->
        <jar destfile="output/testCompas.jar">
            <fileset dir="output" />

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="fr.meteo.dsodos.compas.TestCompas" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                    <section name="common">
                        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="Test du compas magnétique" />
                        <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${versionCAPTEURS}" />
                        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="DSI/DEV/AM" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="Test du compas magnétique" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${versionCAPTEURS} ${TODAY}" />
                        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="DSO/DOS" />
                    </section>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
            
        <echo message="******* capteurs-1.6.jar compilé avec succès *******"/>  
    </target>
```

Comment: add the missing jar [file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.11) in the classpath folder

Comment: sorry but i am begginer you mean in "order and export" tab ?

Comment: You might be having a `lib` folder where the jar files would be placed, can you share your `build.xml` file ?

Comment: Please go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408653/running-junit-from-apache-ant-with-included-jar-file-results-in-junittask-was-n) as well

Comment: `<property name="build.class.prop" id="build.classpath" value="lib/guava-17.0.jar;lib/RXTXcomm.jar;lib/joda-time-2.7.jar;lib/jssc.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;lib/servlet-api.jar" />`
can you add the jar file in this lib folder and then see if it compiles in Eclipse ?

Comment: ok thank you Aak it was that !!