# How put a jar in a Ivy local repository

Tags: java, repository, ivy

I had been studiyng the example of [Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en) but, when I tried to create the example of Service Builder Portlet , my Eclipse-console showed me this message

```
 [ivy:resolve]    http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/2.3.0/bnd-2.3.0.pom
 [ivy:resolve]    -- artifact biz.aQute#bnd;2.3.0!bnd.jar:
 [ivy:resolve]    http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/2.3.0/bnd-2.3.0.jar
 [ivy:resolve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [ivy:resolve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 [ivy:resolve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [ivy:resolve]      :: biz.aQute#bnd;2.3.0: not found 
 [ivy:resolve]      :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
 [ivy:resolve] 
 [ivy:resolve]  
 [ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

effectly, the [repository URL](http://repository.penthaho.org) was unavailable.

I found the missed jar and I put him in **.ivy/cache** and I read the Ivy documentation, but I miss some point for solve my problem.

Now the repository is available, but yet I don't understand how can the repository read the location of jar that I put in local filesystem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sample example which explain how to use filesystem resolver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175000/sample-example-which-explain-how-to-use-filesystem-resolver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your directory

D:\MyWorks\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\
you have to modify file ivj.xml changing the line

dependency name="bnd" org="biz.aQute" rev="2.3.0"

into

dependency name="bnd" org="biz.aQute.bnd" rev="2.3.0"

This should correct the problem.