# how to create dynamic path/fileset elements or other random XML nodes in a build.xml file

Tags: ant

I have a project with a number of compile-time dependencies on other projects (of the same code-base).
So the compile classpath is defined somewhat like the following:

```
<path id = "compile.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${dependency-a.dist.dir}">
    <include name ="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${dependency-b.dist.dir}">
    <include name ="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${dependency-c.dist.dir}">
    <include name ="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${dependency-d.dist.dir}">
    <include name ="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

Also, you can image the corresponding `build` targets for the dependencies and so on.
To reduce repetition I need to somehow generate those structures dynamically.

I thought that one Ant-friendly way to capture those dependencies might be to create a `deps` directory and add sym-links to all the compile-time dependencies of my project.

So the question is: is there an Ant way to write a `macrodef` or a custom Ant task that would scan that directory (or, alternatively, read a configuration file) and expand into/generate the necessary filesets / build targets automatically, in effect changing the XML nodes of the build.xml file at runtime? I am looking for a generic Ant way to do that (if such exist) so I don't have to use the more disruptive way of generating myself the `build.xml` file in its entirety from some other configuration. I am not asking how to use [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) etc. as I am wondering whether there might exist a more sweeping capability of extending/enriching the Ant build file at runtime that would also apply to other cases not involving building dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a task that builds the paths would be pretty easy, but Ant targets are fixed once the build file has been parsed.  Ant builds a directed graph of the targets and then executes them.

It is possible to add new targets via a task that is outside of any target itself.  `include` is such a task.  It might be possible to generate a build file snippet containing the paths and targets you need via a custom task later include it.  Unfortunately `include` won't allow you to embed it in a `macrodef` so the two steps had to appear in pairs.

Of course you can use Ant's API rather than `include` in order to add the paths and targets.  You'd get hold of an existing `Path` using `getReference` on the `Project` instance you've received and add you filesets to it.  Completely new data types use `addReference`, `addTarget` is for targets.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)? It's a dependency manager that provides a set of ANT tasks that can be used control classpaths but it can also download jars from managed repositories (like Maven).

The following answers can give your a flavour of how ivy is used:

- [sample example which explain how to use filesystem resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175000/sample-example-which-explain-how-to-use-filesystem-resolver/10180491#10180491)
- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)

Ivy provides a more powerful solution because it also prevents conflicting versions of the same jar. For example where several dependencies all contain a copy of a common jar like log4j.

In conclusion ivy may appear complex at first glance, but I can assure you that it's solving a complex problem.

Comment: I am using IVY only for external dependencies; for dependencies within the same code base I prefer not to publish them as IVY artifacts but rather directly reference the relative path to where the produced `jar` is located.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus "publish" jars from other builds to a "shared" repository (by default is located "~/.ivy2/shared"). Allows other ivy builds, on the same machine, to pull these in as dependencies. Better still push all jars to a managed Maven repository (like Nexus) and use this as a source of all dependencies. Sounds complicated but ends up being the best solution as it also allows you to shared binaries with other build technologies. In conclusion I'm a big fan of storing the binaries created by my builds. Tagging SCM is fine, but not possible to exactly reproduce a binary.