# filesystem resolver and transitive dependencies / master configurations

Tags: java, ivy

I have setup Ivy with a `filesystem` resolver as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180491/274677). I.e. placing my jars in a 'lib' directory and configuring a `filesystem` resolver to pick them up from there (instead of using the default `ibiblio` resolver).

The file `ivysettings.xml` is as follows:

```
<ivysettings>
  <caches defaultCacheDir="${ivy.settings.dir}/cache"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="local"/>
  <resolvers>
     <filesystem name="local">
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
     </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

My `ivy.xml` is also very simple and for test purposes I only define a single configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="foo" module="foo" status="foo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="theConf"  description="just one configuration"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1" conf="theConf->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

The above works and the dependency is properly retrieved from the `lib` directory. However I've noticed that if I change the dependency element in the `ivy.xml` file to fetch the "master" as opposed to the "default" configuration:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1" conf="theConf->master"/>
```

… then it no longer works and I get the following:

```
resolve: [ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0-local-20161112135640 -
20161112135640 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ :: [ivy:resolve] ::
loading settings :: file =
/home/mperdikeas/play/ivy-with-local-filesystem/ivysettings.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: foo#foo;working@mp-t420
[ivy:resolve]   confs: [theConf] [ivy:resolve]  found
org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 in local [ivy:resolve] ::
resolution report :: resolve 66ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      theConf     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:resolve]  [ivy:resolve] :: problems summary :: [ivy:resolve] ::::
WARNINGS [ivy:resolve]
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]        ::   
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [ivy:resolve]
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]        ::
org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1: configuration not found in
org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1: 'master'. It was required from
foo#foo;working@mp-t420 theConf [ivy:resolve]
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

So even though the module is found it's "master" configuration is not found.

To make this work I either need to change `theConf->master` to `theConf->default` or simply remove the conf mapping altogether.

Further reflecting upon this I realized that I also don't understand how a `filesystem` resolver that's picking up jars laid out flat insider a directory is supposed to distinguish between different configurations and fetch, e.g. only compile time versus transitive dependencies of a module.

At any rate having to always use the "default" configuration causes me problems as I have to modify my `ivy.xml` file. When I resolve using the `ibiblio` resolver I typically have in my `ivy.xml` either:

```
conf="compile->master"
```

… or:

```
conf="runtime->default"
```

… depending on whether I want the transitive dependencies or not. I would like to keep the same `ivy.xml` file regardless of the resolver I have configured to use in `ivysettings.xml`.

My questions are:

1. is it possible to keep the same `ivy.xml` file for both the `ibiblio` and the `filesystem` resolver and what to do with "master" configurations in such a case?
2. how are configurations understood by a `filesystem` resolver that's picking up jars that are laid flat inside a directory?
3. is it possible to configure a `filesystem` resolver such that transitive dependencies can also be fetched with a dependency and what should be the file system structure in such a case?
4. I am simply copying jars inside the directory that the `filesystem` resolver is looking at. Should I be using some importation mechanism instead (e.g. to create the proper directory structure that might perhaps allow the resolver to also fetch transitive dependencies).

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question. Basically you can optionally include ivy files in your "lib" dir to define the configurations and dependencies of each module.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using a flat directory structure with just a bunch of jars. It is clear to me now that in addition to the jars, declarative files need to be present to properly identify the dependencies of each module.

What I have discovered works is to use the `ivy:install` task to import the dependencies I need from the `ibiblio` resolver into my local `filesystem` resolver. More or less as described [in this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190202130657/https://www.codetab.org/apache-ivy-tutorial/apache-ivy-install-task-and-apache-ivy-local-repository/).

I've created a `build-import-Maven-dependencies-to-local.xml` script to automate this process. With some added "cleverness" (which is not crucial and you can dispense with) for aligning all the dependencies visually line after line it looks like the following (the gist is the last target, "install"):

```
<project name="local repository importation" default="install-deps-locally"
         xmlns:contrib="http://net.sf.antcontrib"
         xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <taskdef uri="http://net.sf.antcontrib" resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="${basedir}/tools/ant-contrib.jar" />

    <target name="install-deps-locally" description="local at non default location">
        <!-- "iw" starts for "Import Wrapper" and "d" stands for "dependency" -->
        <antcall target="iw"><param name="d" value="javax.servlet              javax.servlet-api   3.1.0"   /></antcall>
        <antcall target="iw"><param name="d" value="com.google.code.gson       gson                2.8.0"   /></antcall>
        <antcall target="iw"><param name="d" value="junit                      junit               4.12"    /></antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="iw"> <!-- "iw" stands for "Import Wrapper" and "d" stands for "dependency" -->
        <property name="REGULAR_EXPRESSION" value="(\S*)(\s*)(\S*)(\s*)(\S*)"/>
        <contrib:propertyregex property="organisation"
                       input="${d}"
                       regexp="${REGULAR_EXPRESSION}"
                       select="\1"
                       casesensitive="false"/>
        <contrib:propertyregex property="module"
                       input="${d}"
                       regexp="${REGULAR_EXPRESSION}"
                       select="\3"
                       casesensitive="false"/>
        <contrib:propertyregex property="revision"
                       input="${d}"
                       regexp="${REGULAR_EXPRESSION}"
                       select="\5"
                       casesensitive="false"/>
        <antcall target="install">
            <param name="organisation" value="${organisation}"/>
            <param name="module"       value="${module}"/>
            <param name="revision"     value="${revision}"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="install" description="import module from public Maven repository into local repository">
        <ivy:settings id="ivysettings-ibiblio-to-local" file="ivysettings-ibiblio-to-local.xml"/>
        <ivy:install settingsRef="ivysettings-ibiblio-to-local"
                     organisation="${organisation}"
                     module="${module}"
                     revision="${revision}"
                     from="public"
                     to="local"
                     transitive="true"
                     overwrite="true"/>
    </target>    
</project>
```

Resolvers "public" and "local" are defined in the `ivysettings.file` and correspond to `ibiblio` and `filesystem` respectively.

This creates the correct structure and places `ivy-x.y.z.xml` files that provide the necessary information. This is a partial example of the directory structure that got created in my system and the files that are present.

```
$ tree repo/ | head -20
repo/
├── avalon-framework
│   └── avalon-framework
│       ├── ivys
│       │   ├── ivy-4.1.5.xml
│       │   ├── ivy-4.1.5.xml.md5
│       │   └── ivy-4.1.5.xml.sha1
│       └── jars
│           ├── avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar
│           ├── avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar.md5
│           └── avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar.sha1
├── com.google.code.findbugs
│   └── jsr305
│       ├── ivys
│       │   ├── ivy-1.3.9.xml
│       │   ├── ivy-1.3.9.xml.md5
│       │   └── ivy-1.3.9.xml.sha1
│       └── jars
│           ├── jsr305-1.3.9.jar
│           ├── jsr305-1.3.9.jar.md5
```

Once this is in place the `filesystem` resolver works like a charm for both transitive (`default`) and compile-time (`master`) dependencies.